# For which $n$ can $S_n$ act transitively on $n+k$ elements?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-groups

It is known that the symmetric group $S_n$ can act transitively on $n+1$ elements if and only if $n=5$.

Are there similar classifications for $S_n$ acting transitively on $n+k$ elements, where $k$ is fixed? For example, is it known whether there are only finitely many such $n$ for every $k$?

Comment: I think that for $n >7$, there is a gap between $n-1$ and $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ for irreducible character degrees of $S_{n}$ . On the other hand $S_{n}$ does have a transtive permutation representation of degree $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ (on unordered pairs of distinct elements). Yoou may find more information in the books of Fulton and Harris, or James.

Comment: I think you'll find a good overview of what is known in Dixon-Mortimer's *Permutation groups*.

Comment: Of course I forgot that $A_{n-1}$ is a subgroup of index $2n$ in $S_{n}.$

Comment: Just here to point out that this is the same as determining the number of subgroups of index $n+k$, corresponding to the conjugacy class of a fixed point of the transitive action. In particular, by Lagrange's theorem, one needs $(n+k)|n!$. But that's not very restrictive unless $n+k$ happens to be prime. For sufficiently large $n$, if one can prove that all maximal subgroups of $S_n$ are of index $>n+k$ (other than $S_{n-1}$), then this would suffice. One might be able to prove this using the O'Nan-Scott Theorem. But analyzing the almost simple case might be intricate. https://bit.ly/3nWXOZc

Comment: In fact for $n>5$, the smallest set of size greater than $n$ on which $S_n$ acts transitively has size $n(n-1)/2$. The corresponding result for $A_n$, with a lot more detail, is proved in Theorem 5.2A of Dixon & Mortimer - the proof is indeed based on the O'Nan-Scott Theorem. Almost simple maximal subgroups are not problematic, because they are generally much smaller than the intransitive and imprimitive maximal subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt Doesn't $S_n$ act transitively on $S_n/A_{n-1}$ which has size $2n$?

Comment: @Wojowu: Yes it does, as I said above . I think Derek Holt was probably thinking of maximal subgroups and primitive actions, and $A_{n-1}$ is not maximal.

Comment: @DerekHolt : The bound you give works for primitive actions, but is not right for transitive actions in general.

Comment: Note that the answers so far already answer positively the finiteness question, with an explicit bound: if $n>5$, $k>0$ and $n>3/2+(2k+9/4)^{1/2}$ then $S_n$ doesn't act transitively on $n+k$ elements.

Comment: @YCor: : I don't think that is correct in general, for example because of the transitive action of $S_{n}$ on $2n$ points (with point stabilizer $A_{n-1}).$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I should have read more carefully :) this seems to the only exception anyway, and finiteness is still OK.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistakes, I wrote my comment late last night!

Comment: The `bit.ly` link in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381554/for-which-n-can-s-n-act-transitively-on-nk-elements#comment969859_381554) above points to the following Wikipedia page: [O'Nan–Scott theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O'Nan%E2%80%93Scott_theorem). Just posting this in case the URL shortener ends up breaking in the future.

Answer (score 9):

Fix $k > 0$.

Suppose that $n > 6$ and $\frac{n(n-3)}{2} > k$. If $[S_n : H] \leq n+k$, then $H$ is one of the following: $S_n$, $A_n$, $S_{n-1}$, or $A_{n-1}$. So in particular if $[S_n : H] = n+k$, then $k = n$ and $H = A_{n-1}$.

See Theorem 5.2B in "Permutation Groups" by Dixon and Mortimer, and also this Math.SE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536888/large-subgroups-of-symmetric-group/).